# Setting group settings on a 365 group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Microsoft has following sample on their web site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/groupsetting-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp):

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var groupSetting = new GroupSetting
{
    DisplayName = "GroupSettings",
    TemplateId = "08d542b9-071f-4e16-94b0-74abb372e3d9",
    Values = new List<SettingValue>()
    {
        new SettingValue
        {
            Name = "AllowToAddGuests",
            Value = false
        }
    }
};

await graphClient.Groups["{id}"].Settings["{id}"]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(groupSetting);
```

We are trying to disable external access on specific 365 groups. I tried all kind of combinations. But what should the id in Settings["{id}"] be?

Comment: That looks correct to me but you may want `AllowGuestsToAccessGroups` instead of `AllowToAddGuests`.  You can find possible settings in the [PowerShell docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-settings-cmdlets#template-settings).

Comment: Thanks. What would you add to the id of settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/groupsetting-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-update-a-specific-group-setting), it explains that the first {id} in the request is the identifier of the group (group id), and the second {id} is the identifier of the groupSetting object.

To get [groupSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/groupsetting-post-groupsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), you need to create object with the [groupSettingsTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/groupsettingtemplate?view=graph-rest-1.0) and the group settings template id should be with the display name 'Group.Unified.Guest'. You cannot create,delete or update these templates but you can get the template id by using the below http call. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groupSettingTemplates

Here at the time of creation of groupSettings object we need to specify the below values for your condition.

{

"name": "AllowGuestsToAccessGroups",

"value": "false"

}

You can check about this setting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-settings-cmdlets#template-settings) as mentioned by Marc Lafleur.

[Please check this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQo5K.png)

The below call I have used which asks for both id's and the first id is the group id and the second id is the groupSettings object id.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/df951149-7379-44b9-9add-c114e2137d09/settings/87785da2-114b-428a-8983-e65efd24015f